# unable to import rest_framework_simplejwt

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have installed `djangorestframework-simplejwt` package and trying to import that module in `urls.py` and `views.py` but still its not working. Please guide me to solve this issue.

pip list

```
Package                       Version
----------------------------- -------
asgiref                       3.3.1
Django                        3.1.4
djangorestframework           3.12.2
djangorestframework-simplejwt 4.6.0
pip                           20.2.3
PyJWT                         1.7.1
pytz                          2020.4
setuptools                    49.2.1
sqlparse                      0.4.1
```

Settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'Django_MedicalApp',
'rest_framework',
'rest_framework_simplejwt',]


REST_FRAMEWORK = {'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':
                  ['rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',],
              'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': 
('rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny','rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',)}
```

urls.py

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('Company',views.CompanyViewset,basename='Company')


urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('api/',include(router.urls),
path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'))]
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication

class CompanyViewset(viewsets.ViewSet):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
```

Please help me to resolve this import error.

Answer (score 5):

change your interpreter to something else and then choose your virtual env back again. it will work 100%. After installing the simplejwt the interpreter needs to be reset which is achieved by changing the env to something else and back to the virtual env you use normally

[image: select interpreter]

Answer (score 2):

This stems from your Python interpreter. If you are using a virtual environment, please try to select a different venv. In my case

1- I'm using my own venv and import is not successful:

[image]

2- However, when I'm using the global python interpreter, import is okay:

[image]

The reason that it works like that probably we both have something wrong in our venvs.